# DDMS mode in eclipse ,issue pulling a file from an android device

Tags: android

I need to pull an sqlite database my android app is creating to check some details and data, i can do it when using the emulator , but find the "data" folder empty when a i use a real android device,could someone help with this issue ?
thks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was rooted my device and manually extracted the sqlite db from the app's directory.

you can also find apps that extract the db for you! you need to be rooted!